# At what expansion rate (H) would virtual particles be ripped apart into real particles, and what might be the density (temperature) of such an event?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, virtual-particles

Is it even possible for a virtual particle-antiparticle pair to be torn apart by cosmological expansion? Virtual particle-antiparticle pairs are ripped apart near black hole event horizons, creating Hawking Radiation, but can this ever be reproduced by the expansion of space due to a cosmological constant? And if so, at what rate of expansion would this occur? Would the rate have to equal c?

Comment: Yes it's possible. There is a [whole literature](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=cosmological+particle+creation) on it. The temperature of the radiation is related to the "surface gravity" of the cosmological horizon in the same way the Hawking temperature is related to the surface gravity of a black hole.

Comment: Indeed, according to old Jedi wisdom "GR leads to curvature, curvature leads to non unique vacua, and non unique vacua lead to the not-totally-dark side."

Comment: Ha ha @twistor59 LOL :-D. Are you interested in helping to [reopen](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/) some good questions, that already have 4 votes?