# How often can virtual particle/antiparticle pairs form real particles in a space expanding sufficiently fast to do this?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, virtual-particles

And if the rate of expansion of the universe becomes sufficient for virtual particles to be ripped apart into real particles, what effect would the mass of these particles have on the rate of expansion of space? Would it slow the rate down sufficiently to stop the creation of even more particles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [At what expansion rate (H) would virtual particles be ripped apart into real particles, and what might be the density (temperature) of such an event?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70313/)

Comment: It is not a duplicate as it is asking about the backreaction of the radiation on the spacetime. The other question is asking whether pair creation actually takes place.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelBrown that this is not a duplicate: voted to **Leave open**.

Comment: Wow, this is like being on Yahoo Answers...

Comment: So...no actual answers then? Thanks for deciding to leave it open, though...cheers